# Got "HO HO HO" hat today itself, How?

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash-2013

I have earned "HO HO HO" hat today (24th-Dec), Check below ScreenShot.
[image]

But actually its displaying **"Post or vote on Christmas"**, Check below ScreenShot for that.

[image]

May i know whats the reason behind that Or i have had any mistake to understand that?

Comment: Stop wondering and start being jolly!

Comment: since it is 25 dec at utc time so this hate is awarded to its users.now just enjoy it.

Comment: @anilmp40 it isn't 25 at UTC time.